# Not expected response from Spotify API in React code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify

I am making app in React using Spotify API.

First, I obtain access token using my clientID and clientSecret.
Then, I am trying to use this token to obtain userID. [Documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-current-users-profile) says that one needs to make get request and pass token as header.

The problem is, I always have 401 code in response. Documentations mentions that this error probably occurs because token is expired. But in my code I am trying to obtain userID as soon as I get token.

My seconds question is about making request in React. As you can see, I am doing it using useEffect hook, but I don't really know if this is the good approach. Besides, the way I am making second request doesn't feel really nice (that if statement inside useEffect).

Will be appreciated for any help!

P.S. apiKey and apiSecret are global variables, and first request works just fine, it returns valid token, which is successfully used to make another get request for searching songs.

```js
const [token, setToken] = useState("");
const [userID, setUserID] = useState("");

// Obtain access token and user ID
useEffect(() => {
  // Get access token
  const parameters = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    body: `grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=${apiKey}&client_secret=${apiSecret}`,
  };

  fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", parameters)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      setToken(data.access_token);
      return data.access_token;
    });
}, []);

// Obtain user ID once token is obtained
useEffect(() => {
  if (token != "") {
    const parameters = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    };

    fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me", parameters)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
}, [token]);
```

Comment: I would be **extremely** surprised if Spotify allows a `client_credentials` flow from a browser

Comment: See [Which OAuth flow should I use?](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/concepts/authorization#which-oauth-flow-should-i-use). The Client Credentials flow does not even have access to user resources. You should be using the [Authorization Code with PKCE Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-pkce-flow)